# jQCloud not working

Tags: jquery, tag-cloud

I am trying to implement jQCloud library, but when I try to use it my browser shows me

```
$(...).jQCloud is not a function
```

Source of the jqcloud is https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud/blob/master/jqcloud/jqcloud-1.0.4.min.js

The code of the page (with django templatetag):

```
    {% load static %}
    <!doctype html public "lice">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jqcloud</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "home/jqcloud.js" %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var word_list = [
       {text: "Lorem", weight: 15},
       {text: "Ipsum", weight: 9, link: "http://jquery.com/"},
       {text: "Dolor", weight: 6},
       {text: "Sit", weight: 7},
       {text: "Amet", weight: 5}
       // ...other words
    ];
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#wordcloud").jQCloud(word_list);
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wordcloud" style="width: 550px; height: 350px; position: relative;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just open the page in a webbrowser, check the source code of the page in the webbrowser and check if the `jqcloud.js` file is loading correctly...you can also check the Network tab on the Developer Tools(F12 on Chrome), and check if the file is called correctly

Comment: @Hackerman I even moved all the contents from jqcloud.js to the html page, still the same error. BTW, I forgot to mention - there was a (jQuery) at the end of the js file, which I deleted, cause browser console said "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". Maybe its the key?

Comment: I just realize that you need to invert the order of the scripts..first jquery and then jqcloud :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the JQCloud library before it's dependency jQuery.